# Set Pointer (Hand) Cursor Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, mouse-cursor, nscursor

How could I set the cursor to a pointing hand when I hover over an object.
I've tried `[NSCursor pointingHandCursor];` but it didn't work :(

I can hide it like this 
`[NSCursor hide];` but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

`[NSCursor pointingHandCursor];` returns the cursor instance.

You must set if with appropriate method `[[NSCursor pointingHandCursor]set]`